# Scroll View not working in UWP windows 10 IoT core app

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP App I have a `ListView` with many itmes in it.  The problem I have now is that I can't scroll to the last item in the list.

Here is my code:

```
<ListView
        x:Name="AudioFilesLV" 
        Margin="10,146,10,113"
        FontStyle="Oblique"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        ItemClick="SongClicked"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True" RequestedTheme="Default" Foreground="White" CanDragItems="True">
        <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border CornerRadius="25" BorderThickness="2" Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="DarkBlue">
                    <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>
        <ListView.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/background.jpg"></ImageBrush>
        </ListView.Background>
    </ListView>
```

I have added

```
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

but it still doesn't seem to scroll?  I am most likely missing something here :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related with ListView's parent panel, if we place `ListView` in [`StackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layout-panels#stackpanel). *In a StackPanel, if a child element's size is not set explicitly, it stretches to fill the available width (or height if the Orientation is Horizontal). In this example, the width of the rectangles is not set. The rectangles expand to fill the entire width of the StackPanel.* And the ListView's actual height is same as the contentm, so we can't scroll it anymore.

The better way is place ListView in the `Grid` panel, or give it fixed heigt like the following.

```
<ListView Height="300"
    x:Name="AudioFilesLV" 
    Margin="10,146,10,113"
    FontStyle="Oblique"
    FontWeight="Bold"
    ItemClick="SongClicked"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" RequestedTheme="Default" Foreground="White" CanDragItems="True">
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border CornerRadius="25" BorderThickness="2" Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="DarkBlue">
                <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
    <ListView.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/background.jpg"></ImageBrush>
    </ListView.Background>
</ListView>
```